# ¿Cómo puedo modificar los valores de un Array?

Tags: javascript, css, html5

Tengo el siguiente Array:

```
let arr = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Necesito que cuando detecte el numero 2 los siguientes valores se conviertan en 3 intente algo así:

```js
let arr = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

arr.forEach( obj => {
  if(obj == 2 ){
     obj = 3
  }
 
})

const p = document.querySelector(".p")

p.textContent = `[ ${arr} ]`
```

```css
p{
  color: black;
  font-size: 28px;
}
```

```html
<p class="p"></p>
```

No funcionara porque el **obj** no es que modifique al **arr** en si, pero no se que propiedad de los **Array** puede utilizar por ejemplo si mal no estoy **push** solo añade un nuevo dato al Array, al final debería verse así:

```
let arr = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
```

Comment: Usa [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: usando map obtendrás un nuevo array. Si quieres modificar el actual, debes usar un bucle for clásico para recorrer el array y tener acceso para modificar realmente los valores

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podes resolverlo utilizando [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) y [`fill`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) así:

```js
const from = arr.indexOf(2);
if (from >= 0) arr.fill(3, from + 1);
```

#### Ejemplo:

```js
let arr = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
const from = arr.indexOf(2);
if (from >= 0) arr.fill(3, from + 1);

const p = document.querySelector("p");
p.textContent = `[ ${arr} ]`;
```

```html
<p></p>
```

Answer (score 2):

Podría detectar el **índice** del elemento cuyo valor es **2** y luego con un `for` cambiar todos los valores desde ese **índice + 1** en adelante por el valor **3**.

Quedaría algo así:

```js
let arr = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];

const numberTwoIndex = arr.indexOf(2);

for (let i = numberTwoIndex + 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
  arr[i] = 3;
}

const p = document.querySelector("p");

p.textContent = `[ ${arr} ]`;
```

---

Si necesitas que **no se afecte al array original** podrías trabajar con una copia del array orginal, para eso también hay varias opciones.

**Algunos ejemplos:**

```js
let arr = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
let arrCopy = [...arr];

const numberTwoIndex = arr.indexOf(2);

for (let i = numberTwoIndex + 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
  arrCopy[i] = 3;
}

const p = document.querySelector("p");

p.textContent = `[ ${arrCopy} ]`;
```

**Con `.map`**

```js
let arr = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];

const numberTwoIndex = arr.indexOf(2);

const newArray = arr.map((item, i) => (i > numberTwoIndex ? 3 : item));

const p = document.querySelector("p");

p.textContent = `[ ${newArray} ]`;
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacerlo mediante el método [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), que devuelve otro Array de la misma dimensión.

Por ejemplo:

```js
let arr = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
console.log('Antes');
console.log(arr.toString());
const indice = arr.indexOf(2);
arr = arr.map((valor, i) => {
  if( i <= indice) {
    return valor;
  }
  return 3;
});
console.log('Despues');
console.log(arr.toString());
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

También podrías usar el índice directamente en el método `forEach` para actualizar el Array en vivo:

```js
let arr = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
console.log('Antes');
console.log(arr.toString());
const indice = arr.indexOf(2);
arr.forEach((valor, i) => {
  if( i <= indice) {
    return;
  }
  arr[i] = 3;
});
console.log('Despues');
console.log(arr.toString());
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

Sin embargo, en ambos ejemplos se espera que `2` sea parte del Array. Si no aparece, convertirá todos los elementos en `3`, por lo cual debes tomar en cuenta ese caso, ya que no lo especificas en tu pregunta.

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.